# Why $1$ has no unique image under function $x^2 \longrightarrow x, \,x\in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: functions

It is given in the solution to exercise (Q.# $3$, part (ii)) in chap. 1 of the book on Groups, by  R.P. Burns, that 
$x^2 \longrightarrow x, \,x\in \mathbb{R}$ is not a function, as $1$ has no unique image.

I feel confused as $x^2$ is always in $\mathbb{R+}$. Also, $1$ is a positive real.

So, cannot understand the answer.

Comment: Note that $1 = (-1)^2 \mapsto -1$.

Comment: @Trebor You mean to say that both $1, -1$ have same image in the given function, but that is allowed. I mean two domain elements can have the same image.

Comment: It says $x^2 \mapsto x$, not $x \mapsto x^2$.

Comment: $1 = (1)^2 \mapsto 1$ and $1 = (-1)^2 \mapsto -1$. So $1$ has no unique image and thus, this is not a function. I believe this is what @Trebor was saying in the above comments.

Comment: @Nicholas_Roberts Thanks for the elaboration.

Comment: Some reason, apart from confusion caused by question to me, for downvoting would help me in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you need to know is that $x^2\to x$ is not a function but a relation.

It is the inverse of the relation $x\to x^2$. On plotting $x\to x^2$, we get the following graph:

[image]

The curve of its inverse can be obtained by reflecting this in the line-mirror $y=x$

[image]

Now, to find the image of 1, draw the line $x=1$. It cuts the curve at 2 points. Hence 1 has no unique image in the relation $x^2\to x$

Comment: But, the book has another part in the same question that states that over $\mathbb{R}, x\longrightarrow x^2$ is a function. Also, feel that is correct as $x^2$ is always unique as lies in $\mathbb{R+}$, i.e. there a domain element maps to only one (unique) image element.

Comment: That is a function of course bcz it has only one image for every element of the domain

Comment: Please rectify your statement (in answer) then, which states it to be a relation

Comment: Every function is a relation, but the opposite is not true